# Where should I report the bug/feature request for ubuntu-phone to get a better way to position the cursor

Tags: ubuntu-touch, launchpad, bug-reporting

I'm not sure where I should report the following bug/feature request: When you writing something on the ubuntu-phone, finding a spelling mistake and would like to go back to correct it, it is very hard to go to the right position. On android it automatically uses a magnification so you can select it easier. Where would In which package would I have to post this feature request?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best place to file this would be against the ubuntu sdk:
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ubuntu-ui-toolkit

Comment: OK thanks. Here is the link to the bug: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ubuntu-ui-toolkit/+bug/1439149

Answer (score 1):

You can Also use https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Avengers. Alse you can find hints here: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Touch/Bugs